# Xamarin.Android MVVM and SetBindingContext/DataContext

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working on a Xamarin.Android project (Not Xamnarin.Forms). All the tutorials i see are for Xamarin.Froms. I am unable to find anything which explains how to use MVVM pattern for Xamarin.Android project.

In my MainAcitity.cs I Dont have the SetBindingContext/DataContext methods, I am not really sure how can i Bind my ViewModel to my UI.

my VM

```
internal class MainVM : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly DelegateCommand _BtnRegister;
    public ICommand BtnRegister { get; set; }

    public MainVM()
    {
        _BtnRegister = new DelegateCommand(onRegisterClick);
    }

    private void onRegisterClick(object commandParameter)
    {
        
    }
}
```

and here is my Activity File

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);


        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

    }
```

how do i Bind my VM to my Activity?

Comment: Xamarin Android doesn't have built in data binding.  You would need to use a third party framework like MVVMLight, MVVMCross, etc

Comment: any tutorials so i can check them out in action for android?

Comment: I'm sure there are.  Check out the various project sites

Comment: http://www.spikie.be/post/2017/06/23/building-a-netstandard-xamarin-app-with-mvvm-light.html got it